# Ordinals trichotomy property

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

> Given that $A,B$ are ordinals, prove that $A=B$ or $A \in B$ or $B
>  \in A$

**My attempt**

Assume $A \not = B$ and $B \not\in A$ and i want to prove that $A \in B$

Let $C = A \cap B$. I think if I prove $A = C$ I am done.

$C \subset A$ because $ C = A \cap B$ , but I am stuck on the other side.

Proving that $A \subset C$ ?!

I think I need to use the fact that in any non-empty subset of ordinals there is a minimum)

Comment: Hint : Each initial segment of $A$ can be embedded into $B$.

Comment: @Levent I know that C is also ordinal and that if $A,B$ ordinals such that $A \subset B$ then $A \in B$, does this help ??

Comment: This is kind of hard to answer without knowing more context. For example, what sort of assumptions can you already make about the ordinals themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $A\notin B$, $B\notin A$ and $A\neq B$. By symmetry we can assume that there is $C_1\in B\setminus A$.

Then $C_1\subset B$, $A\notin C_1$, $C_1\notin A$ and $C_1\neq A$.

Repeat the same argument with $A$ and $C_1$ to get a $C_2\in$ either $A\setminus C_1$ or $C_1\setminus A$.

You find an infinite sequence of $C_i$ belonging to either $B$ or $A$. This is impossible due to the well-ordering. Therefore $A\notin B$, $B\notin A$ and $A\neq B$ is false.

Comment: thanks, but i did knew this proof, i was looking for an argument that don't  need repeating, so i think the minimum will be helpful here, i just don't know how.

Comment: @Ahmad Just pick $C_1$ to be the first element of $B\setminus A$ and you don't need repeating. It is the same proof, just a matter of how to present it.